# Can you capitalize the first letter while still keeping the rest of the word mixed case?

Tags: python

Can you capitalize the first letter while still keeping the rest of the word mixed case?

For example I want the first letter of a user name capitalized which I can do by;

```
player1 = input('Enter the name of player 1: ').capitalize()
```

If I use this however it *only* capitalizes the first letter and if the are any other capital letters it will change them to lowercase.

Can I force capitalization of the first letter while keeping any other capital letters?

Answer (score 3):

You can capitalize the first letter and keeping the rest by doing so

`string[0].upper() + string[1:]`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
def cap(string):
  return(string[0].upper()+string[1:])
```

For example:

```py
string="cheeSE"
print(cap(string)) # prints "CheeSE"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
player1 = input('Enter the name of player 1: ')
b = player1[0].capitalize() + player1[1:]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Traverse the string, capitalise the first letter, join it again:

`<string_variable>[0].upper()+<string_variable>[1::]`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an inbuilt function that you can use. But you can always create a custom function for the same.

```py
def capitalize_first(s: str) -> str:
    if not s:
        return s
    return s[0].upper() + s[1:]
```